# Celery beat process running on Heroku sends task twice

Tags: django, heroku, celery

I have a periodic task that is being sent twice. I have not been able to figure out the cause.

Celery configuration (in part):

```
app.conf.CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'email-todays-todos': {
        'task': 'apps.todo.tasks.email_todays_todos',
        'schedule': crontab(hour='7', minute='30')
    },
    'send-onboarding-emails': {
        'task': 'apps.home.tasks.send_onboarding_emails',
        'schedule': crontab(hour='13', minute='0')
    },
}
```

The first periodic task (`email_todays_todos`) sends once with no problem, but the second one (`send_onboarding_emails`) sends twice.

My Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn appname.wsgi
worker: celery -A appname worker -l info
beat: celery -A appname beat
```

Here is what is happening in the logs:

```
Mar 10 11:00:00 appname app/beat.1:  [2014-03-10 13:00:00,162: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task send-onboarding-emails (apps.home.tasks.send_onboarding_emails) 
Mar 10 11:00:00 appname app/beat.1:  [2014-03-10 13:00:00,101: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task send-onboarding-emails (apps.home.tasks.send_onboarding_emails) 
Mar 10 11:00:00 appname app/worker.2:  [2014-03-10 13:00:00,259: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: apps.home.tasks.send_onboarding_emails[a4dcb6ff-fa40-4a9c-beba-21c62b0bd5e5] 
Mar 10 11:00:01 appname app/worker.1:  [2014-03-10 13:00:00,450: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: apps.home.tasks.send_onboarding_emails[f97c546d-5876-4152-8344-96bd05c546b1] 
Mar 10 11:00:05 appname app/worker.2:  [2014-03-10 13:00:05,564: INFO/MainProcess] Task apps.home.tasks.send_onboarding_emails[a4dcb6ff-fa40-4a9c-beba-21c62b0bd5e5] succeeded in 5.00695208088s: True 
Mar 10 11:00:07 appname app/worker.1:  [2014-03-10 13:00:05,455: INFO/MainProcess] Task apps.home.tasks.send_onboarding_emails[f97c546d-5876-4152-8344-96bd05c546b1] succeeded in 4.76427294314s: True
```

I have 2 dynos running for the worker process and 1 dyno running for the beat process.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am experiencing this with two different heroku apps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Not sure if this will work for you but I ended up removing the CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE from my settings file and instead created a periodic task in my tasks.py file. Just decorate the function you want to run like so:

@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=30))

I had mine run every 30 seconds, but you can change it to whatever interval you want.